# Debian 11, Nagios4, and 403 forbidden

Tags: apache2, nagios

Having installed Debian's Nagios4 package I can't access it. Apache gives me this:

```
AH01797: client denied by server configuration: /usr/share/nagios4/htdocs
```

I've tried various things, such as changing ownership of the relevant directories to the www-data user & group (apache2 is running as this user), and editing config files to add the permission for that directory:

/etc/apache2/conf-available/nagios4-cgi.conf

```
...
<Directory /usr/share/nagios4/htdocs>
    Options     +ExecCGI        
    Order allow,deny
    Require all granted
</Directory>
...
```

/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/

```
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/nagios4 /usr/lib/cgi-bin/nagios4
ScriptAlias /nagios4/cgi-bin /usr/lib/cgi-bin/nagios4
Alias /nagios4/stylesheets /etc/nagios4/stylesheets
Alias /nagios4 /usr/share/nagios4/htdocs
<DirectoryMatch (/usr/share/nagios4/htdocs|/usr/lib/cgi-bin/nagios4|/etc/nagios4/stylesheets)>
    Options FollowSymLinks
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
    AllowOverride AuthConfig
    #Require ip ::1/128 fc00::/7 fe80::/10 10.0.0.0/8 127.0.0.0/8 169.254.0.0/16 172.16.0.0/12 192.168.0.0/16
    <Files "cmd.cgi">
        AuthDigestDomain "Nagios4"
        AuthDigestProvider file
        AuthUserFile    "/etc/nagios4/htdigest.users"
        AuthGroupFile   "/etc/group"
        AuthName        "Nagios4"
        AuthType        Digest
        Require all     granted
    </Files>
</DirectoryMatch>
<Directory /usr/share/nagios4/htdocs>
    Options     +ExecCGI        
    Order allow,deny
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Can anyone think of anything I've missed?

Comment: Both `<DirectoryMatch>` and `<Directory>` directives match the path `/usr/share/nagios4/htdocs`. Apache will only use one of these.

Comment: Apart from that you are mixing Apache 2.2 and 2.4 directives, [which is discouraged](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/upgrading.html#run-time) because it leads to possible problems. Your Apache should be 2.4, so you should remove the old 2.2 directives.

Comment: Good point about the mixed directives. I have tried removing /usr/share/nagios4/htdocs from the DirectoryMatch line (though this file was otherwise as the default) with no change.

Answer (score -1):

The eventual answer was to move instructions from the Directory block into the DirectoryMatch block, in particular `Require all granted`.